# How exactly is Miles Morales (1610) camouflage power explained to work in-universe?

Tags: marvel, spider-man, miles-morales

That's about it: I'm asking about the possible mechanics of Miles’ power, as they explain it in comic canon.

Also curious as to the "Real world" possible explanation, but trying to basically understand how it's put forth in-comic. The power *itself*, I gather, is based around the "natural" camouflage ability many species of spiders possess, but it's unclear why Miles has it or how it works, as the spider-sense is described as a "buzzing a the base of the skill that radiates throughout the cranium in reaction to proximity of threat."

As early as the 2002 Sam Raimi  *Spider-Man* film, the audience is informed that "some spiders can blend into their surroundings," and this is true; Wrap-Around spiders, Knobbly head spiders, and huntsman spiders are just some breeds that can accomplish this. There's even a pure color changing spider that can mimic its background....

[image] [image]

[image] [image]

So this is very much a *real* phenomenon. So I can buy this being a power Miles gained from such latent spider genes. However, these arachnids manage this being completely naked and altering themselves to match their surroundings.

Miles, on the other hand, has a comparatively more complex, sizable, and distinctly human physical structure; where as the spiders adapted to mimic nature and its phenomenon, Miles is very much in urban landscapes and dressed in different colors and materials. Yet, *somehow,* his "Camo" power manages to make him *seamlessly* blend into *any* background, effectively going unseen by regular vision.

The confusing thing is this power seems to work even when Miles is near *nothing* to "blend" in to. This makes his power seem less like "camouflage", and work more akin to true "invisibility"....

[image] [image]

Even if we take into account that Miles can do this, the power seems to effect not only him, but **his clothes, too!**

[image]

This would be difficult enough, considering as he moves, his background would be changing.

So,the main question basically is **How does Miles Camo power *actually* work in-universe?**

Was there ever an explanation given to the possible *mechanics* of it (light refraction, a chemical process, or some other thing?)

Why does it effect his clothing and nearby gear, as well?

Does he "control" the power mentally, or is it more passive?

Was there ever a canon explanation of how this ability functions?

Comment: Additionally, how does he see when invisible.

Comment: Related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/218072/why-did-miles-morales-get-non-spider-like-powers-bio-electrokinesis-and-invisib — though this doesn't go into the mechanics

Answer (score 2):

According to [the official Marvel.com profile](https://www.marvel.com/characters/spider-man-miles-morales/in-comics/profile), it is a function of his bio-electric powers:

> However, unlike Peter Parker, he also has bio-electrokenisis (sic) powers, including the ability to stun enemies with a "venom blast" and camouflage into his surroundings.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  It would make for a better answer if you quoted the relevant portions of the page you are linking to, rather than just posting a link.  You might want to read [answer].

Comment: It's worth pointing out that although this info is hosted on marvel.com, it's been cribbed from the old (fan-written) Marvel wiki. Still a decent find though.

Comment: Ok.... how the _hell_ would electrical conduction and resistance  allow him to seamlessly effect visual perception of others?

Yes, I'm willing to accept even _quasi_ sci-fi answers here. That doesn't even sound like a "hand wave", just  "throw it in there".